# Download file without redirect if correct password

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On the admin panel of my website I have a list of all auto-generated backup files of the database from which a user can click to download any of these files. However, for added security, I'd like to implement a text-field in which the user has to enter a special PIN-code in order to download a backup-file; like this:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="PIN Code" name="pin" />
<button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
```

First I was thinking to have an event triggered when the user clicks the button and via Ajax call a php-script which checks the password (and potentially any anti-flooding measures). If the script generates no errors it will return "OK" and download can commence.

But I only recently started playing around with Ajax and it seems like Ajax cannot download files. Redirecting the user to the path wouldn't work because the directory has chmod 770.

So my question is, how can I do this while maintaining security and without having to redirect/refresh the page?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use jQuery File Download for AJAX-like file downloads http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: @RuubW, yes I have seen that one. I'm unsure if this approach is suitable for protected files though. My problem is also different in that a php-script needs to be run first before the rest can start.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand why you can't use a redirect, but try serving the file from your php script

For example, if the download link is on /downloads.php, have the form submit back to itself (action="/downloads.php" method="POST") and if the pin is correct the user downloads the file and is returned to the previous page. If not correct, it acts like a page refresh.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pin']) && isset($_POST['filename']) && check_pin($_POST['pin'])) {
    header('Content-Type','application/sql');
    header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="' . $filename ."');
    print file_get_contents($filename);
}
else {
// the rest of your page
}
?>
```

*Please forgive my code, it has been a couple years since I last used php, and thus it may have errors.